# Generalizing "inner" generics - how?

Tags: java, generics

Imagine the following code:

```
final Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = validator.validate(user);
```

while `User` is defined as

```
public class User extends SuperModel {
```

Now, I want to pass the `violations` to a method like

```
    private void checkViolations(final Set<ConstraintViolation<? extends SuperModel>> violations) {
    // do something        
}
```

So I want this helper method to be generic as I do not need to know that the `ConstraintViolation`s in the `Set` are of the type `User`.

But the compiler says:

```
Error:(46, 25) java: incompatible types: java.util.Set<javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<my.package.model.User>> cannot be converted to java.util.Set<javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<? extends my.package.model.SuperModel>>
```

I do not really understand why this is impossible, because every `User` is a `SuperModel`. This should work IMO.

In contrast, here is something that works:

```
private void checkViolation(ConstraintViolation<? extends SuperModel> violation) {
    // do something
}

private void otherMethod() {
    [...]
    final Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = mValidator.validate(user);
    for (ConstraintViolation<User> violation : violations) {
        checkViolation(violation);
    }
}
```

Does my first example not work because there are two "levels" of generics involved?

Comment: Parent-child relations of classes does not imply the same for collections of these classes.

Comment: It is not the nestedness of type arguments which makes this not work. `Set` is a so-called 'invariant' type function. That is, `A > B` (meaning `B` is a subset of `A`) implies neither `Set<A> > Set<B>` nor `Set<B> > Set<A>`. To see this, think about the two operations of adding and iterating over the set. On the other hand, `Iterable` is 'covariant', meaning `A > B` implies `Iterable<A> > Iterable<B>`. So in your case, `Iterable<ConstraintViolation<? extends SuperModel>>` should work.

Comment: @Oly That does not fix the underlying issue of the constraint for the wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `? extends SuperModel` means anything that extends `SuperModel` can be used.

If you want to pass `Set<ConstraintViolation<User>>` to the wildcard it will not be accepted, because you break the *anything extends SuperModel* with `User` only.

Keep in mind that you can pass anything with the constraint `? extends SuperModel`. So the Set might consist of a `User`, a `SuperModel` or something entirely different which extends `SuperModel`.

```
private void checkViolation(final Set<ConstraintViolation<? extends SuperModel>> violation) {
    // you know that the Set consists of any object extending SuperModel.
}
```

Use this instead

```
private <T extends SuperModel> void checkViolations(final Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations) {
         // you know the Set consists only of object of type T      
    }
```

By declaring the type `T` you ensure that ever item in the list is of type `T`. So the Set can only consist of `User`, `SuperModel` or any other type extending `SuperModel`.

Answer (score 0):

`Set<ConstraintViolation<User>>` is not a subtype of `Set<ConstraintViolation<? extends SuperModel>>` even though `ConstraintViolation<User>` is a subtype of `ConstraintViolation<? extends SuperModel>`, for the same reason that `Set<String>` is not a subtype of `Set<Object>` even though `String` is a subtype of `Object`.

Basically, when a generic type is parameterized by type and not a wildcard, the parameter must match exactly. `Foo<A>` is only compatible with `Foo<B>` if `A = B` exactly. If you want to be polymorphic on the type parameter, the generic type must be parameterized by a wildcard, e.g. `Foo<A>` is a subtype of `Foo<? extends B>` if `A` is a subtype of `B`. (Note that in the case of `Set<ConstraintViolation<? extends SuperModel>>`, `Set` is parameterized by the type, not a wildcard. There is a wildcard somewhere inside the type `ConstraintViolation<? extends SuperModel>`, but `Set` only cares about the top level.)

If you want to be able to accept `Set<ConstraintViolation<X>>` and `Set<ConstraintViolation<Y>>`, etc., one way to do it is with a wildcard at the top level:

```
private void checkViolations(final Set<? extends ConstraintViolation<? extends SuperModel>> violations) {
```